# Every delivered email shows unique open while the email is not opened (not even seen)

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I've created a journey in MC which sends a welcome email as soon as the entry source is triggered. It is synced with Salesforce via MCC so the entry source is salesforce data. Whenever a salesforce contact is created, the subscriber enters the journey.

As we are testing it: The problem is, the email delivered to the subscriber automatically shows unique open while the email is not opened (not even seen). Thus, the next step is engagement split and it considers the email as opened and ends the journey for the subscriber. The journey is set to send another email if the subscriber doesn't open the first email. But it never reaches that step. As shown in the screenshot below.

[image: First Email's analytics]

-I have the email opens tracking code included in the email.
-I tried creating a new journey but it didn't solve the problem.
-Changed the email template as well. Still the same.

Also note: The Time duration is set to 2 minutes just for testing purposes.

Every little help is appreciated. Much Thanks!

Comment: What email client are you sending to. Gmail app will sometimes prefetch images which would register an open

Comment: well, it happens every time. Though it's a good catch. I'll try with multiple clients. Although I've had it tested earlier with an email containing images at Gmail which seemed to work fine. But now it's troubling.

Comment: also just an idea.. do you fetch the html of the newsletter during send or something?

Comment: Is it potentially a firewall or something on your targeted subscribers that is scanning the email on delivery (usually only a 'thing' for corporate email addresses though)?  Those would create 'bot' opens and 'bot' clicks on your tracking as the images would be loaded which would fire the open pixel.

Comment: I don't think so. We are testing it on general emails. Personal+Business. @EazyE 's point is valid that it's an issue with Gmail. I tried sending an email to a different client which seemed to work fine. After which, I sent an email to Gmail which also worked fine. Once again when I sent an email to Gmail, the behavior was changed and it again started considering email as opened. As a side note, we do not repeat emails. Each time there is a new email. I'm still trying to figure out the problem that could be with the Gmail client. trying with different image formats. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone out there still facing the same problem:

As mentioned in the comments on my question, it happened only with the Gmail client. To resolve this problem, I contacted Salesforce support and explained the situation. They contacted Gmail Support and reached the conclusion that it is a problem with the email IP from Salesforce. Then, we had to purchase our own SAP from Salesforce which resolved the problem after IP warming and everything.